# Working with SASS in Adobe Dreamweaver

Tags: file, dreamweaver, sass

I am trying to figure out how to start using SASS files in Dreamweaver.

The error message I get when trying to open is: "Can't find a valid editor for this file extension".

All my SASS files are valid and open well with Eclipse.

Thanks in advance to anyone who could post any tips on this one.

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/editors.html does not list Dreamweaver as a supporting Sass editor. Does it mean that having one of the most popular and most expensive text editors on the market I won't be able to code in this great and fairly popular meta-language?

Comment: This is an old question, but in case anyone gets here from Google: Dreamweaver 2017 now includes full scss support including a built in processor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. I have found the answer.

All you need to do is open Dreamweaver, go to Edit> Preferences> File Types / Editors
and in the top text box ("Open in code view:") listing various files extensions add .sass.

That's it. Rest is down to haml and compass.

I hope this post will help anyone having similar problem.

Comment: Back in a day I was still using the old sass syntax - but the same would apply to .scss

Answer (score 4):

To go even further and make Dreamweaver treat .scss files as .css files (applying code coloring and indentation), just follow the instructions on this [Adobe TechNote](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16410.html)

Comment: Many thanks for this link, Alonso. I did try it yesterday in CS5. I found the Extensions.txt and edited it but in this new version of Dreamweaver the folder structure must be slightly different as I couldn't locate the  MMDocumentTypes.xml file. So highlighting sass as css is not working for me yet, but I'll give it another go and also test it on other machine with CS3 and post the results here, as soon as I get there.

Answer (score 4):

The visual28 link no longer works.  Here is a quick rundown from [here](http://shang-liang.com/blog/syntax-highlighting-for-sass-in-dreamweaver/)

```
DreamweaverCS?/Configuration/DocumentTypes/MMDocumentTypes.xml
```

If Windows  change `winfileextension="css"` to `winfileextension="css,scss"`

If Mac change `macfileextension="css"` to `macfileextension="css,scss"`

Answer (score 3):

For older Dreamweaver:

http://www.visual28.com/articles/less-scss-syntax-highlighting-in-dreamweaver

For Dreamweaver 5.5 and above:

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/861133

Answer (score 3):

instead to go in your installation directory to find the 'MMDocumentTypes.xml' file, GO to

> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver
>   CS5?\en_US\Configuration\DocumentTypes\MMDocumentTypes.xml

and then find `winfileextension="css"` and change it to  `winfileextension="css,scss"`...

That would definitely work..

Comment: That was definitely what was missing for me - the changes to MMDocumentTypes.xml file in Program Files wasn't doing anything. Changing the file in AppData did.

Answer (score 2):

1. Update to the latest version of Dreamweaver
2. Ensure that ‘Show hidden files’ is enabled in Control Panel > Folder options
3. Open your user folder eg C:\users\Dylan\ replacing with your name
4. Then open AppData/Roaming/Adobe/Dreamweaver CS6/en_US/Configuration/
5. Open the file Extensions.txt
6. Replace the first line with the following:

> HTM,HTML,SHTM,SHTML,HTA,HTC,XHTML,STM,SSI,JS,JSON,AS,ASC,ASR,XML,XSL,XSD,DTD,XSLT,RSS,RDF,LBI,DWT,ASP,ASA,ASPX,ASCX,ASMX,CONFIG,CS,CSS,LESS,SCSS,CFM,CFML,CFC,TLD,TXT,PHP,PHP3,PHP4,PHP5,PHP-DIST,PHTML,JSP,WML,TPL,LASSO,JSF,VB,VBS,VTM,VTML,INC,SQL,JAVA,EDML,MASTER,INFO,INSTALL,THEME,CONFIG,MODULE,PROFILE,ENGINE,SVG:All
>   Documents

7. Replace the following line:

> CSS:Style Sheets

With

> CSS,LESS,SCSS:Style Sheets

8. Save and exit the file
9. Go to the folder DocumentTypes
10. Open the file named MMDocumentTypes.xml
11. Replace the line beginning with:

=>documenttype id="CSS"

with

```
 <documenttype id="CSS" internaltype="Text"
 winfileextension="css,less,sass,scss" macfileextension="css"
 file="Default.css" writebyteordermark="false" mimetype="text/css" >
```

12. Save and exit the file, and restart Dreamweaver
13. Syntax highlighting now works